# addEventListener onload can be set or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the follow code

```
cost.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
quantity.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
```

they update inputs if I change something but I have a input that must be autofilled when page load

The input 1 has the product price cost comming from MySQL
I have another input quantity with default value set to 1

The input 3 changes to total cost perfect using cost * price IF I change quantity manually but when page load it show some addEventListener to the cost * quantity onload and not only when I manually do it editing quantity?

something like

```
totalcost.addEventListener('onpageload', updateInput);
```

Comment: when you're using addEventListener, you need to use the actual event name like `load` unlike `onload` in attachEvent

Comment: An example in a fiddle would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run some code when the page first loads, you can do that in jQuery with this (you tagged your question with jQuery so you may as well use it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your code here that runs when the page first loads
});
```

Or, you can do this in plain Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // put your code here that runs when the page first loads
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're using `addEventListener` to register event handlers, you need to pass the event name as string without on, so it should be `load` event in case of page load

```
window.addEventListener('load', updateInput);
```

For a complete list of supported browser events, have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: An individual DOM element (unless it is an image, an iframe or the window object) does not have a `load` event.

Comment: Oops.. my mistake :) I thought OP's talking about page load

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming your situation, I have put together a demo with the following code. All you need to do is to invoke the function that does the calculation when page is loaded as well.

```js
var f = document.querySelector("#first");
var s = document.querySelector("#second");
var r = document.querySelector("#result");

function updateInput() {
    r.value = parseFloat(s.value) * parseFloat(f.value);
}

f.addEventListener("keyup", updateInput);
s.addEventListener("keyup", updateInput);

//Additional line to trigger the function when page is loaded.
window.addEventListener("load", updateInput);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="second" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="result" value="" readonly="" />
```

The values of the first 2 inputs are multiplied and the result is displayed in the last input, on key up and page load. Hope that helps.